# Capture video full screen with AVCaptureSession

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I need my app to display a live preview of what the front camera is filming, and this video stream's dimensions need to match the screen size of the device.

But there are black bars appearing at the top and bottom of the preview view... 
[image]

How can capture and preview video that has the dimensions of the full screen? Note I don't want to resize the video!

Below is my code:

```
session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];

[session addInput:input];

UIView *cameraPreviewView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] ;
[self.view addSubview:cameraPreviewView];

AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
[session addOutput:output];

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *cameraPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
cameraPreviewLayer.frame = cameraPreviewView.bounds;

[cameraPreviewView.layer addSublayer:cameraPreviewLayer];
[cameraPreviewLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[cameraPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect];

[session startRunning];
```

Comment: try to “NSLOG” the frame for cameraPreviewLayer and UIView; I think this is the culprit: cameraPreviewLayer.frame = cameraPreviewView.bounds; …